# Getting most recent distinct records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Considering the following table:

```
User  CreatedDateTime   Quantity
----- ----------------- --------
Jim   2012-09-19 01:00  1
Jim   2012-09-19 02:00  5
Jim   2012-09-19 03:00  2
Bob   2012-09-19 02:00  2
Bob   2012-09-19 03:00  9
Bob   2012-09-19 05:00  1
```

What query would return the most recent rows (as defined by `CreatedDateTime`) for each `User`, so that we could determine the associated `Quantity`.

i.e. the following records

```
User  CreatedDateTime   Quantity
----- ----------------- --------
Jim   2012-09-19 03:00  2
Bob   2012-09-19 05:00  1
```

We thought that we could simply `Group By` `User` and `CreatedDateTime` and add a `Having MessageCreationDateTime = MAX(.MessageCreationDateTime`. Of course this does not work because `Quantity` is not available following the `Group By`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server, you can use [Window Function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) on this.

```
SELECT [User], CreatedDateTime, Quantity
FROM
    (
        SELECT [User], CreatedDateTime, Quantity,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY CreatedDateTime DESC) as RowNum
        FROM tableName
    ) a
WHERE  a.RowNum = 1
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e08c1/1)

Answer (score 4):

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT [User], CreatedDateTime, Quantity, 
   rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY CreatedDateTime DESC)
  FROM dbo.table_name
)
SELECT [User], CreatedDateTime, Quantity
FROM x WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have the ability to use windowing functions, then you can use a sub-query:

```
select t1.[user], t2.mxdate, t1.quantity
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
    select [user], max(CreatedDateTime) mxdate
    from yourtable
    group by [user]
) t2
    on t1.[user]= t2.[user]
    and t1.CreatedDateTime = t2.mxdate
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1be9/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
User, 
CreatedDateTime, 
Quantity
FROM 
YourTable
WHERE 
CreatedDateTime = 
(SELECT MAX(CreatedDateTime) FROM YourTable t WHERE t.User = YourTable.User)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from <table_name> where CreatedDateTime in (select max(CreatedDateTime) from <table_name> group by user) group by user;
```

Comment: No, that will return the record `Bob   2012-09-19 03:00  9`, which is incorrect.