# PowerApps: Filter by multiple condition and distinct by one further condition

Tags: powerapps

My gallery shows all the records from my list in which filter statements are true, as follows:

```
Filter(table_name,
             Filter_A = Column_A
             And Filter_B = Column_B)
```

This works perfectly fine, but I'd need now to add another filter, as per the following logic:

> If Column_A And Column_B are non-unique, returning more than 1 row, then return only the latest Column_C (Date-Time field)

My guess was:

```
Filter(table_name,
             Filter_A = Column_A
             And Filter_B = Column_B
             And Max(Column_D)
             )
```

When Filter_A = "yellow", and Filter_B = "X", my result right now looks like this:

```
 Column_A | Column_B | Column_C | Column_D
 yellow   |    X     |    1     | 04/05/19
 Yellow   |    X     |    2     | 01/02/19
 Yellow   |    X     |    3     | 01/03/19
 Yellow   |    X     |    1     | 01/02/19
```

but I'd want this:

```
 Column_A | Column_B | Column_C | Column_D
 yellow   |    X     |    1     | 04/05/19
 Yellow   |    X     |    2     | 01/02/19
 Yellow   |    X     |    3     | 01/03/19
```

PS
Although I want to show in the gallery only the most recent record in case of duplicates, I still need to keep those "duplicates" on the list.
PPS
A perfect example of what I'm trying to do, although for sql not PowerApps, [may be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496857/getting-most-recent-distinct-records)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I can't quite make out the logic you're looking for, but you'll likely want to investigate the [PowerApps `Distinct` function][1].


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-distinct